# Cannot connect to SQL Server due to SSL/TLS

Tags: linux, nginx, .net-core, sql-server-2012, .net-5

I have been getting this error since setting up my Linux server to host a dotnet application, where it tries to connect to the database engine SQL Server running on a windows environment (version 2012). The linux server is running .Net 5 and I have tried to have a certificate under `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` folder with no luck so far. I also have nginx configured to use ssl:

```
server {
listen        80;
listen        443 ssl;
server_name   111.111.111.111;

ssl on;

ssl_certificate /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cert.crt;

ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cert.key;

location /core/ {
    proxy_pass         https://127.0.0.1:7001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

//The Error

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)
```

//Connectiong String

```
"Server=111.111.111.111\\TESTDB4;Initial Catalog=Core;User ID=demo;Password=password;Integrated Security=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Trusted_Connection=True;Encrypt=True;"
```

Comment: Use a tool like Wireshark to analyze how the TLS handshake fails. That's more important than trying every tip you found.

Comment: @LexLi will look into it, I feel like at this point I just been throwing everything against the wall

Answer (score 1):

You need to consume the certificate on your web server. I dont know exactly where to add it exactly but I guess it should be included on your database connection string

Comment: I did try a few connection string variations with `Encrypt=True/False` `TrustServerCertificate=True/False`, if that is what you are thinking of.

Comment: It may be a linux user problem. you are not using different users for deploying the service solution and the database right?

Comment: Correct, a different user on linux, my connection string does have the login credentials for a user I created on SQL Server